# Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to install postgresql-server-dev-9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I first did `sudo apt-get install postgresql` and it worked. I then tried `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1` and i get the error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-9.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-server-dev-9.1'
```

I am really a total newbie so handholding and spoonfeeding will be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04, `Postgresql` is on Version 9.3. Just try to install `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev` or `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Trusty Tahr (i.e. 14.04) has:

`postgresql-server-dev-9.3`

instead of

`postgresql-server-dev-9.1`

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5
```